# Trying to get just the text from a node with filter(), but is returning an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, text

I am simply trying to extract the text without any of the elements from a DOM node with

```
var textIWant = $('.classname').contents().filter(function(){
                    return this.nodeType === 3;
                })[1];
```

This returns to me what *looks* like a string in the console, something untrimmed like..

```
"           text I want      "
```

so when I go to trim the text, with something like

```
$.trim(textIWant)
```

I get

> "[object Text]"

also as you would expect,

```
typeof textIWant
```

returns "object"

Why is this string looking object not a string, and how can I get the string I need? I cannot use methods such as String() or toString() it will just convert it to the same "[object Text]" that I put above.

**EDIT
I also want to add that I am working with a proxy server, so I do not have direct access the the original HTML written, otherwise, the common sense solution would be to wrap the text in an HTML tag and query for it using jQuery's .text(). My question comes from an edge case scenario not unfamiliarity with jQuery :).

** Answer

Something like this seemed to do the trick

```
$.trim($($('.classname').contents().filter(function(){
                    return this.nodeType === 3;
                })[1]).text())
```

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `TextNode` object so need to read it thusly:

```
var text = $(textIWant).text();
```

Or natively

```
var text = textIWant.nodeValue;
```

Comment: I see no need in this question to deal with text nodes at all.  Much better to just ask jQuery for the text of an element with `.text()` as other answers show.

Comment: Indeed however understanding reduces future confusion

Comment: @JustinRusso - The OP's question deals with text nodes.  That's the question being asked here and what this should be an answer to.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason in your question for why you need to deal with text nodes directly yourself at all.  jQuery will fetch text for you.

If you only have a single object that matches `.classname` then the simpler way to get the text from that element is with:

```
var textIWant = $.trim($(".classname").text());
```

This will collect the text from all textnodes that are within the `.classname` element.  There is no need for you to filter through them yourself.

---

If you may have more than one element that matches `.classname` and you only want the text from the first one, then you can use this:

```
var textIWant = $.trim($(".classname").eq(0).text());
```

---

In the future, if you do have a textNode DOM element and you wish to retrieve the text from it, you can use `node.nodeValue` to get the text from a textNode.

---

As to your other questions:

> Why is this string looking object not a string, and how can I get the
>   string I need?

You were retrieving the text node DOM object, not the text from the node.  You can use `node.nodeValue` to get the actual text from the text node and then you will have a string that you can operate on as a string.

> I cannot use methods such as String() or toString() it will just
>   convert it to the same "[object Text]" that I put above.

This is because you had a text node, not a string.  You just have to get the text out of the node so you can then use it as a string.

Comment: Two things here, the first is that jqueries .text() function will get all the text from that .classname, and the text from the children of that node. I only want to retrieve the text from the node I am selecting, so therefore filtering is necessary. The second thing is that I am working with a proxy, so I do not have access to the immediate html that is being written, otherwise I would just save myself the stress and wrap the text in a <p id="textIwant">  and just query for that.

Comment: @DirkDunn - next time show the actual HTML and describe what text you're trying to get from that and you will get much more accurate answers.  We're guessing what source HTML you're trying to deal with because you didn't show it to us.  Keep in mind the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (where you describe only issues with your solution and not the actual problem you're trying to solve) makes it a LOT harder for us to give the best and accurate answers.  I would have provided a more useful answer if you showed the whole actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use .toString() in your code before assigning that to "textIWant" variable or you can convert it to string by this function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp

Note: If your object is a DOM element you may use "text" function from jquery:
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

`textIWant` is a Text node. Therefore when you throw it into the `$.trim` it will try to run it on an object.

You would want to ask for the `textContent` of the TextNode

like so.

```js
$.trim(textIWant.textContent); //Does not work in IE8 or below
```

or like Alex K. suggested use jQuery to get the text from the node using `.text()`

```js
$.trim($(textIWant).text);
```

http://jsbin.com/welidanihe/edit?html,js,console